# Arcpad checkout to an area

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-desktop, arcpad

I would like to check out data from an SDE database but for performance sake, i prefer to delete all features outside of my survey area.

i've tried to copy features in area from sde to a file GDB then checkout , but the checkin could not be perfect, because i can only synchronize new added features to sde database. so i cannot synchronize modified or deleted features.

i've tried to checkout directly from sde Database then delete all features outside area using Bounding box query , but it take much time once i start arcpad after checkout.

i'm using Arcpy to checkin and checkout.

Any help please.

Comment: Are you working with a .axf file in ArcPad?

Comment: yes i working with .axf file resulted from an Arcpad checkout

Comment: Are you using the ArcPad toolbox tools for checkin/checkout.  If so, can you select features in your map from a version and drag that layer into the checkout tool?

Comment: i'm not using arcmap , i'm using just arcpy script for checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a three-step process. You'll need to use ArcMap for the two steps to configure your project, but once your project is configured you can use this configuration as many times as you need to.

1. First create your mxd with your data in it and zoom to the region you want to check out. Once your project is configured you will only check out data in this region.
2. From the ArcPad Data Manager toolbar in ArcMap run the [Configure Project for Geoprocessing tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/Configure_Project_for_Geoprocessing/00s10000006n000000/). Going through this wizard will create an .apo file in the same folder as your mxd.
3. From the toolbox (or in Python) run the [Process ArcPad Project](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/Process_ArcPad_Project/00s1000000n6000000/) tool on the mxd you've configured. This mxd with the apo file can be used to check in and out data as often as is needed.

Unfortunately without configuring your project in ArcMap first there is no way to restrict the region being checked out in arcpy.